# Check if user exists in database in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, exists

My problem is that I want to check if username in registration page already exists in database to prevent multiple same names but got an error

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

Here is my code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)           //tworzymy Zapytanie wraz z połączeniem z bazą
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registrationConn"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string sprawdz = "Wybierz count (*) from Uzytkownicy where Nazwa_uzytkownika='"+un.Text+"'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sprawdz, conn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32((String)com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());  <----The error moment
            if(temp==1)
            {
                Response.Write("Uzytkownik o podanej nazwie już istnieje.");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `Wybierz statement` in T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
string sprawdz = "Wybierz count (*) from Uzytkownicy where Nazwa_uzytkownika='"+un.Text+"'";
```

with

```
string sprawdz = "select count (*) from Uzytkownicy where Nazwa_uzytkownika='"+un.Text+"'";
```

*I am not a Polish speaker but checked on google that Wybierz is a Polish word which means select* ([Link](http://mymemory.translated.net/t/Polish/English/wybierz))

So logically and syntactically **it should be select not Wybierz**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend in this case to do this per **stored procedure** with SQL.

Why?
Stored procedures are **compiled once and stored** in executable form, so procedure calls are quick and efficient. Executable code is automatically cached and **shared among users**. This **lowers memory requirements** and invocation overhead.

So Code like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CheckIfUserExists",conn);
cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoreProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",un.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsExists",0);
int rowAffected=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
// rowAffected contains your Result
```

And procedure like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  CheckIfUserExists   
(    
    @UserName Varchar(50),  
    @IsExists INT OUTPUT   
)   
AS      

If exists (select Nazwa_uzytkownika from Uzytkownicy where Nazwa_uzytkownika = @username)   
Begin

Set @IsExists = 1

End     
Else   
begin

Set @IsExists = 0

End

Return @IsExists
```

Hope so i got this right with polish.

Comment: Additional information: Procedure or function 'CheckIfUserExists' expects parameter '@UserName', which was not supplied.

I added procedure, it shows when i click event button on my register page.

Comment: Changed the cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",un.Text);

Comment: Additional information: Procedure or function 'CheckIfUserExists' expects parameter '@IsExists', which was not supplied.

Comment: Added Line: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsExists",0);

Comment: Where exacly? because when i add it  just after query starts it set @IsExists on 0 no matter what it really is?

Comment: See changes, after the other Parameter Line